# Performance of C++11 modern-style loops vs old-style loops

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, foreach, auto

This is the first question I'm posting here, so I hope I won't do anything wrong.

My question concerns the performance of modern-style C++11 loops (`std::for_each`, range-based for) vs old-style C++ loops (`for (...; ...; ...)`). From what I understood, it seems to me that the motto of modern C++ is "expressivity with no compromise on performance". Modern C++ style leads to safe, clean, and fast code with little to no performance penalty and, possibly, with a performance gain over old-style C++.

Now I've made a little test to assess how big this gain is concerning *loops*. First I wrote the following three functions:

```
using namespace std;

void foo(vector<double>& v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        v[i] /= 42;
    }
}

void bar(vector<double>& v)
{
    for (auto& x : v)
    {
        x /= 42;
    }
}

void wee(vector<double>& v)
{
    for_each(begin(v), end(v), [] (double& x)
    {
        x /= 42;
    });
}
```

Then I compared their performance by calling them this way (properly commenting/uncommenting the three lines inside `main()`'s loop:

```
vector<double> make_vector()
{
    vector<double> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30000; i++) { v.push_back(i); }
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    time_t start = clock();

    auto v = make_vector();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 50000; i++) 
    { 
        // UNCOMMENT THE FUNCTION CALL TO BE TESTED, COMMENT THE OTHERS

        foo(v);
        // bar(v); 
        // wee(v);
    }

    time_t end = clock();
    cout << (end - start) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Averaging over 10 executions of each version of the program obtained by commenting/uncommenting the lines in `main()`'s loop, and using the old-style loop as a baseline, the range-based for loop performs ~1.9x worse, and the loop based on `std::for_each` and lambdas performs ~2.3x worse.

I used Clang 3.2 to compile this, and I haven't tried MS VC11 (I'm working on WinXP).

Considering my expectation of getting comparable execution times, my questions are:

1. Did I do something obviously wrong?
2. If not, couldn't a 2x performance penalty be a good reason NOT to embrace modern-style loops?

I would like to remark, that I do believe that the clarity and safety of code written in modern C++ style pay off for a possible performance loss, but I quite disagree with the statement that there is no trade-off between clarity/safety on one side and performance on the other side.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I just ran your code (compiled with Clang) and all three ran in approximately the same amount of time. Do you have optimisation enabled in your compiler?

Comment: What is the resolution of clock() for your compiler and are your results within its margin of error?

Comment: Integer division is typically a high latency instruction on most architectures, so your loop overhead may be insignificant - try using addition instead.

Comment: @Mankarse: I am a beginner, so I might indeed be doing something wrong. I use the following command line: 'clang test.cpp -o test.exe -std=c++11 -I"C:\progra~1\clang\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.1\include\c++" -I"C:\progra~1\clang\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.6.1\include\c++\mingw32" -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.1/../../.. -L/mingw/lib -lstdc++ -lmingw32 -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 [...]` (omitted only some more -l switches)

Comment: @AndyProwl: Add `-O3` to enable heavy optimisation.

Comment: @PaulR: I'not sure I understand your point: I am doing the same operation within each loop, so the overhead should be imputable just to the loop. Am I wrong? I just tried addition, but the comparison is roughly the same (a bit worse actually: as one of the answers points out, the heavier the loop body the less significant is the impact of the loop's efficiency).

Comment: @Mankarse: OK, thanks for the tip, obviously I was missing something fundamental. I get comparable execution times now. Thank you!

Comment: @Mankarse: I would like to give a "Thumbs up" to your comment and state that it answers my questions, but I couldn't find a way to do that. Could you maybe re-post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it? Thank you

Comment: Why time the `make_vector` call? This is constant overhead for each test (but of course the time will vary slightly each run, giving you fuzzier results unnecessarily).

Comment: @GManNickG: You are absolutely right, I overlooked that one and `make_vector()` should certainly *not* be timed. Actually, not timing it would make the difference even bigger. However, the whole point is that my comparison was flawed as I was not using the -O3 flag in the command line. Optimization really makes the execution times comparable, so there's really no loss in performance, which is what I was concerned with.

Comment: As a footnote, check out this tech talk by C++ guru Alexandrescu on principles of C++ optimization (slides in the link in the comments): http://vimeo.com/55639112

Comment: I happened to watch this video last week, but thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like the difference only shows up when you do not enable optimisations in your compiler.

With Clang you can enable optimisation with the `-O[0-3]` flag.

Answer (score 10):

[Mankarse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14056730/1762344) is right - most likely you have not enabled optimizations.

Actually on Clang they produce practically same result ASM code in main loop, and small difference in pre/post code.

I have tested four versions: `hand_loop_index`, `hand_loop_iterator`, `range_based_for`, `for_each_algorithm`

`hand_loop_iterator`, `range_based_for` and `for_each_algorithm` - all three do produce **exactly same result ASM** for full function body, only difference is in names of labels.

I.e. hand written for loop with iterators results in exactly same ASM code as range-based-for and std::for_each.

There are some differences between loop with index and loop with iterator versions.

Main loop in both cases is almost same. The only minor differece is that for iterators version(s) `rdx` register is used instead of `rsi`.

## Index version:

```
.LBB0_7:                                # %vector.body
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movupd  -48(%rsi), %xmm1
    movupd  -32(%rsi), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -48(%rsi)
    movupd  %xmm2, -32(%rsi)
    movupd  -16(%rsi), %xmm1
    movupd  (%rsi), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -16(%rsi)
    movupd  %xmm2, (%rsi)
    addq    $64, %rsi
    addq    $-8, %rdi
    jne .LBB0_7
```

## Iterator version(s):

```
.LBB1_6:                                # %vector.body
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movupd  -48(%rdx), %xmm1
    movupd  -32(%rdx), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -48(%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm2, -32(%rdx)
    movupd  -16(%rdx), %xmm1
    movupd  (%rdx), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -16(%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm2, (%rdx)
    addq    $64, %rdx
    addq    $-8, %rsi
    jne .LBB1_6
```

Pre/post code for index vs iterator versions has many differences, but it should not affect greatly total result timing for large enough arrays.

## [**LIVE DEMO on Coliru with ASM output**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/abb9d53fdde588fb)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void hand_loop_index(vector<double> &v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
        v[i] /= 42;
    }
}

void hand_loop_iterator(vector<double> &v)
{
    for (auto first = begin(v), last = end(v); first!=last; ++first)
    {
        *first /= 42;
    }
}

void range_based_for(vector<double> &v)
{
    for (auto &x : v)
    {
        x /= 42;
    }
}

void for_each_algorithm(vector<double> &v)
{
    for_each(begin(v), end(v), [] (double &x)
    {
        x /= 42;
    });
}
```

## Result ASM:

```
# clang++ -std=c++1z -O3 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -S
    .text
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .align  16
.LCPI0_0:
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 4.200000e+01
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 4.200000e+01
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align  8
.LCPI0_1:
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 42
    .text
    .globl  _Z15hand_loop_indexRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z15hand_loop_indexRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE,@function
_Z15hand_loop_indexRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE:  # @_Z15hand_loop_indexRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    movq    8(%rdi), %rcx
    subq    %rax, %rcx
    je  .LBB0_11
# BB#1:                                 # %.lr.ph
    sarq    $3, %rcx
    cmpq    $1, %rcx
    movl    $1, %edx
    cmovaq  %rcx, %rdx
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .LBB0_10
# BB#2:                                 # %overflow.checked
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    movq    %rdx, %r8
    andq    $-4, %r8
    je  .LBB0_9
# BB#3:                                 # %vector.body.preheader
    cmpq    $1, %rcx
    movl    $1, %edi
    cmovaq  %rcx, %rdi
    addq    $-4, %rdi
    movq    %rdi, %rsi
    shrq    $2, %rsi
    xorl    %r9d, %r9d
    btq $2, %rdi
    jb  .LBB0_5
# BB#4:                                 # %vector.body.prol
    movupd  (%rax), %xmm0
    movupd  16(%rax), %xmm1
    movapd  .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm2   # xmm2 = [4.200000e+01,4.200000e+01]
    divpd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    divpd   %xmm2, %xmm1
    movupd  %xmm0, (%rax)
    movupd  %xmm1, 16(%rax)
    movl    $4, %r9d
.LBB0_5:                                # %vector.body.preheader.split
    testq   %rsi, %rsi
    je  .LBB0_8
# BB#6:                                 # %vector.body.preheader.split.split
    cmpq    $1, %rcx
    movl    $1, %edi
    cmovaq  %rcx, %rdi
    andq    $-4, %rdi
    subq    %r9, %rdi
    leaq    48(%rax,%r9,8), %rsi
    movapd  .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0   # xmm0 = [4.200000e+01,4.200000e+01]
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_7:                                # %vector.body
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movupd  -48(%rsi), %xmm1
    movupd  -32(%rsi), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -48(%rsi)
    movupd  %xmm2, -32(%rsi)
    movupd  -16(%rsi), %xmm1
    movupd  (%rsi), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -16(%rsi)
    movupd  %xmm2, (%rsi)
    addq    $64, %rsi
    addq    $-8, %rdi
    jne .LBB0_7
.LBB0_8:
    movq    %r8, %rdi
.LBB0_9:                                # %middle.block
    cmpq    %rdi, %rdx
    je  .LBB0_11
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_10:                               # %scalar.ph
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movsd   (%rax,%rdi,8), %xmm0    # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    divsd   .LCPI0_1(%rip), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, (%rax,%rdi,8)
    incq    %rdi
    cmpq    %rcx, %rdi
    jb  .LBB0_10
.LBB0_11:                               # %._crit_edge
    retq
.Lfunc_end0:
    .size   _Z15hand_loop_indexRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE, .Lfunc_end0-_Z15hand_loop_indexRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .cfi_endproc

.section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .align  16
.LCPI1_0:
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 4.200000e+01
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 4.200000e+01
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align  8
.LCPI1_1:
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 42
    .text
    .globl  _Z18hand_loop_iteratorRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z18hand_loop_iteratorRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE,@function
_Z18hand_loop_iteratorRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE: # @_Z18hand_loop_iteratorRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    movq    (%rdi), %rdx
    movq    8(%rdi), %rax
    cmpq    %rax, %rdx
    je  .LBB1_11
# BB#1:                                 # %.lr.ph.preheader
    movabsq $4611686018427387900, %rsi # imm = 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFC
    leaq    -8(%rax), %rcx
    subq    %rdx, %rcx
    shrq    $3, %rcx
    incq    %rcx
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    movq    %rcx, %r9
    andq    %rsi, %r9
    je  .LBB1_8
# BB#2:                                 # %vector.body.preheader
    andq    %rcx, %rsi
    leaq    -4(%rsi), %rdi
    movq    %rdi, %r11
    shrq    $2, %r11
    xorl    %r10d, %r10d
    btq $2, %rdi
    jb  .LBB1_4
# BB#3:                                 # %vector.body.prol
    movupd  (%rdx), %xmm0
    movupd  16(%rdx), %xmm1
    movapd  .LCPI1_0(%rip), %xmm2   # xmm2 = [4.200000e+01,4.200000e+01]
    divpd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    divpd   %xmm2, %xmm1
    movupd  %xmm0, (%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm1, 16(%rdx)
    movl    $4, %r10d
.LBB1_4:                                # %vector.body.preheader.split
    leaq    (%rdx,%r9,8), %r8
    testq   %r11, %r11
    je  .LBB1_7
# BB#5:                                 # %vector.body.preheader.split.split
    subq    %r10, %rsi
    leaq    48(%rdx,%r10,8), %rdx
    movapd  .LCPI1_0(%rip), %xmm0   # xmm0 = [4.200000e+01,4.200000e+01]
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB1_6:                                # %vector.body
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movupd  -48(%rdx), %xmm1
    movupd  -32(%rdx), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -48(%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm2, -32(%rdx)
    movupd  -16(%rdx), %xmm1
    movupd  (%rdx), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -16(%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm2, (%rdx)
    addq    $64, %rdx
    addq    $-8, %rsi
    jne .LBB1_6
.LBB1_7:
    movq    %r8, %rdx
    movq    %r9, %rdi
.LBB1_8:                                # %middle.block
    cmpq    %rdi, %rcx
    je  .LBB1_11
# BB#9:
    movsd   .LCPI1_1(%rip), %xmm0   # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB1_10:                               # %.lr.ph
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movsd   (%rdx), %xmm1           # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
    divsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    movsd   %xmm1, (%rdx)
    addq    $8, %rdx
    cmpq    %rdx, %rax
    jne .LBB1_10
.LBB1_11:                               # %._crit_edge
    retq
.Lfunc_end1:
    .size   _Z18hand_loop_iteratorRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE, .Lfunc_end1-_Z18hand_loop_iteratorRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .cfi_endproc

.section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .align  16
.LCPI2_0:
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 4.200000e+01
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 4.200000e+01
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align  8
.LCPI2_1:
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 42
    .text
    .globl  _Z15range_based_forRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z15range_based_forRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE,@function
_Z15range_based_forRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE:  # @_Z15range_based_forRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    movq    (%rdi), %rdx
    movq    8(%rdi), %rax
    cmpq    %rax, %rdx
    je  .LBB2_11
# BB#1:                                 # %.lr.ph.preheader
    movabsq $4611686018427387900, %rsi # imm = 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFC
    leaq    -8(%rax), %rcx
    subq    %rdx, %rcx
    shrq    $3, %rcx
    incq    %rcx
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    movq    %rcx, %r9
    andq    %rsi, %r9
    je  .LBB2_8
# BB#2:                                 # %vector.body.preheader
    andq    %rcx, %rsi
    leaq    -4(%rsi), %rdi
    movq    %rdi, %r11
    shrq    $2, %r11
    xorl    %r10d, %r10d
    btq $2, %rdi
    jb  .LBB2_4
# BB#3:                                 # %vector.body.prol
    movupd  (%rdx), %xmm0
    movupd  16(%rdx), %xmm1
    movapd  .LCPI2_0(%rip), %xmm2   # xmm2 = [4.200000e+01,4.200000e+01]
    divpd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    divpd   %xmm2, %xmm1
    movupd  %xmm0, (%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm1, 16(%rdx)
    movl    $4, %r10d
.LBB2_4:                                # %vector.body.preheader.split
    leaq    (%rdx,%r9,8), %r8
    testq   %r11, %r11
    je  .LBB2_7
# BB#5:                                 # %vector.body.preheader.split.split
    subq    %r10, %rsi
    leaq    48(%rdx,%r10,8), %rdx
    movapd  .LCPI2_0(%rip), %xmm0   # xmm0 = [4.200000e+01,4.200000e+01]
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB2_6:                                # %vector.body
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movupd  -48(%rdx), %xmm1
    movupd  -32(%rdx), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -48(%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm2, -32(%rdx)
    movupd  -16(%rdx), %xmm1
    movupd  (%rdx), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -16(%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm2, (%rdx)
    addq    $64, %rdx
    addq    $-8, %rsi
    jne .LBB2_6
.LBB2_7:
    movq    %r8, %rdx
    movq    %r9, %rdi
.LBB2_8:                                # %middle.block
    cmpq    %rdi, %rcx
    je  .LBB2_11
# BB#9:
    movsd   .LCPI2_1(%rip), %xmm0   # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB2_10:                               # %.lr.ph
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movsd   (%rdx), %xmm1           # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
    divsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    movsd   %xmm1, (%rdx)
    addq    $8, %rdx
    cmpq    %rdx, %rax
    jne .LBB2_10
.LBB2_11:                               # %._crit_edge
    retq
.Lfunc_end2:
    .size   _Z15range_based_forRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE, .Lfunc_end2-_Z15range_based_forRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .cfi_endproc

.section    .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
    .align  16
.LCPI3_0:
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 4.200000e+01
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 4.200000e+01
    .section    .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
    .align  8
.LCPI3_1:
    .quad   4631107791820423168     # double 42
    .text
    .globl  _Z18for_each_algorithmRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .align  16, 0x90
    .type   _Z18for_each_algorithmRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE,@function
_Z18for_each_algorithmRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE: # @_Z18for_each_algorithmRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    movq    (%rdi), %rdx
    movq    8(%rdi), %rax
    cmpq    %rax, %rdx
    je  .LBB3_11
# BB#1:                                 # %.lr.ph.i.preheader
    movabsq $4611686018427387900, %rsi # imm = 0x3FFFFFFFFFFFFFFC
    leaq    -8(%rax), %rcx
    subq    %rdx, %rcx
    shrq    $3, %rcx
    incq    %rcx
    xorl    %edi, %edi
    movq    %rcx, %r9
    andq    %rsi, %r9
    je  .LBB3_8
# BB#2:                                 # %vector.body.preheader
    andq    %rcx, %rsi
    leaq    -4(%rsi), %rdi
    movq    %rdi, %r11
    shrq    $2, %r11
    xorl    %r10d, %r10d
    btq $2, %rdi
    jb  .LBB3_4
# BB#3:                                 # %vector.body.prol
    movupd  (%rdx), %xmm0
    movupd  16(%rdx), %xmm1
    movapd  .LCPI3_0(%rip), %xmm2   # xmm2 = [4.200000e+01,4.200000e+01]
    divpd   %xmm2, %xmm0
    divpd   %xmm2, %xmm1
    movupd  %xmm0, (%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm1, 16(%rdx)
    movl    $4, %r10d
.LBB3_4:                                # %vector.body.preheader.split
    leaq    (%rdx,%r9,8), %r8
    testq   %r11, %r11
    je  .LBB3_7
# BB#5:                                 # %vector.body.preheader.split.split
    subq    %r10, %rsi
    leaq    48(%rdx,%r10,8), %rdx
    movapd  .LCPI3_0(%rip), %xmm0   # xmm0 = [4.200000e+01,4.200000e+01]
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB3_6:                                # %vector.body
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movupd  -48(%rdx), %xmm1
    movupd  -32(%rdx), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -48(%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm2, -32(%rdx)
    movupd  -16(%rdx), %xmm1
    movupd  (%rdx), %xmm2
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    divpd   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movupd  %xmm1, -16(%rdx)
    movupd  %xmm2, (%rdx)
    addq    $64, %rdx
    addq    $-8, %rsi
    jne .LBB3_6
.LBB3_7:
    movq    %r8, %rdx
    movq    %r9, %rdi
.LBB3_8:                                # %middle.block
    cmpq    %rdi, %rcx
    je  .LBB3_11
# BB#9:
    movsd   .LCPI3_1(%rip), %xmm0   # xmm0 = mem[0],zero
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB3_10:                               # %.lr.ph.i
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    movsd   (%rdx), %xmm1           # xmm1 = mem[0],zero
    divsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    movsd   %xmm1, (%rdx)
    addq    $8, %rdx
    cmpq    %rdx, %rax
    jne .LBB3_10
.LBB3_11:                               # %_ZSt8for_eachIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPdSt6vectorIdSaIdEEEEZ18for_each_algorithmR5_E3$_0ET0_T_SA_S9_.exit
    retq
.Lfunc_end3:
    .size   _Z18for_each_algorithmRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE, .Lfunc_end3-_Z18for_each_algorithmRSt6vectorIdSaIdEE
    .cfi_endproc

    .ident  "clang version 3.7.0 (tags/RELEASE_370/final 246979)"
    .section    ".note.GNU-stack","",@progbits
```